# How to move server project to my localhost?

Tags: apache, magento, xampp, localhost, mamp

What I'm asking is not how to move localhost to remote server.

I'm new to server so I don't know how to move project I have to open? launch? at my localhost.

I try to develop Magento at localhost and develop and test Magento service at my own laptop localhost.

But I'm in troubling moving my project cloned using GitHub to my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install wamp, start it's services.
2. clicking the wamp icon in your system tray will allow you to access 'phpmyadmin'- use the databases tab to create a new db (for development at home I typically leave the db user and password as 'root').
3. Inside wamp's install directory is the 'www' folder. create a subdirectory within it, download magento and extract it into your newly created subdirectory.
4. If you unzipped your magento files to c:/wamp/www/myproject then point your browser at 127.0.0.1/myproject and you should see the magento installation page. Follow it through until you finish installing.
5. Now when you go to 127.0.0.1 you should see the front page of a fresh magento install. appending the url with /admin will let you log into the back end. Do this, and then navigate to system -> cache management and disable all the caches.
6. You can now copy across any work you've already done on the project into your relevant magento folders (presumably /app and /skin)

Comment: I'm a mac user , after chaning wamp -> mamp, it would be working too?

Comment: yes should work fine in mamp also.
Create your project subdirectory in MAMP/htdocs instead of wamp/www

Comment: I think to access phpmyadmin via wamp you'll need to point your browser at 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin and then log in with username 'root' and a blank password